# Errors while putting object on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to get temperature value from DynamoDB table and calculating the average of that values and sending average value to S3 bucket. I calculated the Average value but when putting that value to s3 bucket I got the error:

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': positional argument follows keyword argument (lambda_function.py, line 45)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 45\n        s3.put_object(Bucket='mys3pooja', Key='time', Body=val)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is not an S3 error, Your error in in the function being executed

Answer (score 1):

Error you're shown is syntax related.

If you have function or method with signature like `def foo(bar, foo="something")`, it has positional argument `bar` and keyword argument `foo`. Python's convention is to always put positional arguments before keyword ones when you call this function, so `result = foo(1, foo="text")` is correct, but `result = foo(foo="text", 1)` is incorrect

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? `bar` is positional and `foo` is keyword?

Comment: @Marcin yeah I mixed them up, fixed